# SharePoint 2010 Upgrade Status

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I recently installed the CU for Feb 2013 and ran the PSConfig GUI. This generated a Upgrade Session that listed Warnings and Errors etc (I have some missing web parts etc). Once I have fixed the issues that the log reported, how do get another Upgrade Session to run?

I have run the PSConfig GUI many times but I can't see a new record in the Upgrade Sessions.

Comment: Does the "Review Database Status" reveal anything?

Comment: The Database Status is "no Action Required" for all. This was expected as it was recently upgraded to the latest CU anyway. I know there are still Server Side Dependancy Issues as I see then when I run Test-SPSContentDatabase. But yet this does not show up in the Health Monitor yet. What Timer job runs that check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if there are any updates needed via Central Administration > Upgrade and Migration > Review Database Status.

If your databases need updating, you can run the following command:

```
PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

Do this from the following directory:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN

If all goes well, your update session status will now be "succeeded".

Comment: Perfect! I thought the "SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard" GUI was supposed to do the same thing, but I guess not. I ran that commange twice and both times got Succeeded with zero error and zero warnings! Thanks.